# How were the Potters so rich?

Tags: harry-potter, lily-potter

It seems that Harry's parents left him a pretty sizable fortune. They were pretty young when they had Harry and when they died. I dont remember much talk about their professions. How did they manage to amass such a fortune at such a young age?

Comment: They created Harry Potter! cha-ching!